# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/eq-cloudwebapp]]

Tags: java, spring, servlets, web-applications, tomcat9

I am stuck with this error, where a component fails to start, and not sure how to fix this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Environment:

- Gradle 5.4.1
- jdk 11.0.15 (11.0.15+8-LTS-149)
- tomcat 9.0.64
- I am using the SmartTomcat plugin to run project.

What I've tried:

- added log4j.jar to dependencies
- cleared browser cache
- double checked environment variables

Notes:

servlet-api.jar from tomcat added to project libs

This is the catalina log:

```
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/eq-cloudwebapp.main]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
http://localhost:8080/eq-cloudwebapp.main
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/eq-cloudwebapp.main]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:250)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:2136)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;

Maybe your servlet version is too low, the getClassLoader method is only available above servlet 3.0

Comment: hi @Aooohan, first i used tomcat 9.0.64 servlet-api which is javax.servlet version 4.0 which also had classLoader in it, I swapped it to javax.servlet-api-3.0-alpha-1, but the error stayed the same.